Toggle on/off a virtual keyboard to persist and stay active onscreen (and not disappear offscreen)
Is there a way to toggle on/off a virtual keyboard to stay onscreen and not disappear offscreen when the cursor is not in an active editable text field?
I'm using a Samsung device if it's relevant.
